# How to add style to li before attribute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is the timeline chart what I have to draw a circle before every li element.

```css
ul.timeline>li:before {
  content: ' ';
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #22c0e8;
  left: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <h4>Latest News</h4>
      <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <a target="_blank" href="https://www.totoprayogo.com/#">New Web Design</a>
          <a href="#" class="float-right">21 March, 2014</a>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque scelerisque diam non nisi semper, et elementum lorem ornare. Maecenas placerat facilisis mollis. Duis sagittis ligula in sodales vehicula....</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">21 000 Job Seekers</a>
          <a href="#" class="float-right">4 March, 2014</a>
          <p>Curabitur purus sem, malesuada eu luctus eget, suscipit sed turpis. Nam pellentesque felis vitae justo accumsan, sed semper nisi sollicitudin...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Awesome Employers</a>
          <a href="#" class="float-right">1 April, 2014</a>
          <p>Fusce ullamcorper ligula sit amet quam accumsan aliquet. Sed nulla odio, tincidunt vitae nunc vitae, mollis pharetra velit. Sed nec tempor nibh...</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I change the color of the border, on the HTML element?

Here is the complete example: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-vertical-timeline

Comment: Change the `border-color` of which “*HTML element*”?

Comment: I am not sure how I can do this because I am using, li:before and so i dont have html element

Comment: Do you want to change circle color or anchor tag underline color?

Comment: which border should be another color?

Comment: @JayKumar change here `border: 3px solid red;` currently you are using in hex unit border color.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to add the border between two blue circles, also want to remove the default `ul` style.
I have added a bit of `css` code to your code. Check it out below.

- To remove the default `ul` style, I have added `list-style-type` as
  `none`.
- To add the vertical line connecting the list items, I
  have added a pseudo class element `:before` to `ul.timeline`.

```css
ul.timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.timeline:before {
    content: ' ';
    background: #d4d9df;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 29px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 400;
}
ul.timeline>li:before {
  content: ' ';
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #22c0e8;
  left: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <h4>Latest News</h4>
      <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <a target="_blank" href="https://www.totoprayogo.com/#">New Web Design</a>
          <a href="#" class="float-right">21 March, 2014</a>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque scelerisque diam non nisi semper, et elementum lorem ornare. Maecenas placerat facilisis mollis. Duis sagittis ligula in sodales vehicula....</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">21 000 Job Seekers</a>
          <a href="#" class="float-right">4 March, 2014</a>
          <p>Curabitur purus sem, malesuada eu luctus eget, suscipit sed turpis. Nam pellentesque felis vitae justo accumsan, sed semper nisi sollicitudin...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Awesome Employers</a>
          <a href="#" class="float-right">1 April, 2014</a>
          <p>Fusce ullamcorper ligula sit amet quam accumsan aliquet. Sed nulla odio, tincidunt vitae nunc vitae, mollis pharetra velit. Sed nec tempor nibh...</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timeline using only Bootstrap classes (no extra CSS) like this. The `border` utility class is used to create the lines.

```
    <!-- timeline item -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- timeline item 1 left dot -->
        <div class="col-auto text-center flex-column d-none d-sm-flex">
            <div class="row h-50">
                <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <h5 class="m-0">
                <span class="badge badge-pill bg-light border">&nbsp;</span>
            </h5>
            <div class="row h-50">
                <div class="col border-right">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- timeline item 1 event content -->
        <div class="col py-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Timeline item content....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/AX0ugyF5Vd

Answer (score -1):

You can the border color to whatever you want 
Please check this screen shot we change it on the live example

https://irfan-ranksol.tinytake.com/sf/MzAzMzMyN185MDkxMDMx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @Paulie_D according to this question we cannot add all the css of the area he provide the link on run time and we point out at the same link that you can do this